# "The property ... was not found in type ...", why doesn't this appear in build results?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, compiler-warnings

I'm working on a C# WPF application, using Visual Studio 2022.

While running the application, I saw a checkbox, whose value did not change, although it should. This was caused by the following typo in the corresponding XAML-file:

```
IsChecked="{Binding SelectedProduct.Enable}"
```

While is should be:

```
IsChecked="{Binding SelectedProduct.Enabled}"
```

(mind the last letter of the property.)

I could easily see this in the XAML editor (there was a blue wave, indicating the error).
Then I started wondering if there would be other mistakes like this in my source code (there are lots of XAML files), so I decided to type the same error again and see what the compiler warning/hint/... would be, but to my surprise this kind of error/warning/hint/... is not even shown.

I believe there should be some configuration setting for this, but I have no idea where to look for this, hence my question:

In case I make spelling mistakes in my XAML-files, where should I look for an overview of those mistakes, preferably during the build of my application?

Thanks in advance

**Edit after first answer:**
I've found the "enable XAML" thing, but on another spot:
"Tools" menu, "Options", "XAML Designer", "General", and it looks as follows:

[image: XAML Designer screenshot]

As it is already enabled, then why don't I see anything?

On the place, mentioned by [Francesco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22568563/francesco-pippi), there is the following (the small dialog box is shown after having clicked the "Advanced" button):

[image: General project Build output screenshot]

Comment: A similar setting is about showing XAML designer errors, located at: Tools => Options => Text Editor => Xaml => Miscellaneous => show errors detected by the xaml designer. But this option may not meet your requirements. [Live Visual Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging?view=vs-2022&toc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Fdebugger%2Ftoc.jsonDoes#look-at-elements-in-the-live-visual-tree) meet your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid the binding paths are not evaluated during compile time in WPF. There is no support for [compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) using `x:Bind`.

At *runtime*, you'll see warnings about binding failures if you debug the application in Visual Studio and have the `Data Binding` option set to anything else than `Off` in the Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window > WPF Trace Settings dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just checked your reputation and you seem to be a C#, WPF and XAML expert. Do you have any idea if such a feature is about to be implemented and where this can be monitored?

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/130) on GitHub from 2018. You'll also find a link to a community implementation (untested) of this there.